# find matrix A given its exponential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm given $e^{At}$ and I need to find A

From http://www.math24.net/method-of-matrix-exponential.html
I see that $$\frac{d}{dt}(e^{At})=Ae^{At}$$

so does it mean, that to answer my question I just need to differentiate $e^{At}$ and the resulting coefficients would give me my matrix?

Comment: Exactly. (A more gentlemanly way of putting it is to observe that $A=\tfrac{d}{dt}(e^{At})(e^{At})^{-1}$)